# Json not being parsed ConvertAPI

Tags: json, parsing, asp-classic, convertapi

I'm using classic asp & JSON to convert html to pdf. I send the request using the following:

```
        ''Convert output to pdf
        varURL = "https://" & varServerLive & "/import/" & fileName

        postURL = "https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/htm/to/pdf?Secret=SECRET_KET&File=" & varURL & "&StoreFile=true"
        parmToSend = "{""Parameters"":[{""Name"":""File"",""FileValue"":{""url"": """ & varURL & """}}," & _
            "{""Name"":""WebHook"",""Value"":""" & varURL & """}" & _
            "]}"

        Set ServerXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
        ServerXmlHttp.open "POST", postURL
        ServerXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        ServerXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        ServerXmlHttp.send parmToSend

        ''Get response
        responseText = ServerXmlHttp.responseText
        response.write(responseText)

        set myJson = JSON.parse(responseText)
        varFileUrl = myJson.Files.Url
        response.write(varFileUrl)
```

I get the following response:

responseText:

```
{"ConversionCost":2,"Files":[{"FileName":"54-25062020177.pdf","FileExt":"pdf","FileSize":48596,"FileId":"542c6f079fe5722bdbac2f73f84652d3","Url":"https://v2.convertapi.com/d/542c6f079fe5722bdbac2f73f84652d3/54-25062020177.pdf"}]}
```

Which is all good, but when I try to return the fileURL I get an error:

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6'

Object doesn't support this property or method: 'url'

/docs/members/cert.asp, line 122

Do you see any reason why the url is not being returned? Am I calling the url correctly (eg. myJson.Files.Url)?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's because `Files` is an array so you need to specify which object in the array you are getting the `Url` property of. What JSON parser are you using?

Comment: Interesting, you seem to be returning different response data than [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62555555/692942). Personally, prefer the request where the Base64 data is returned in the response because this method will require another HTTP call to get the file from the Url, which seems a pointless step.

Comment: Yes, I've changed the request to return thr url of the created pdf rather than the fileData.

Comment: Im using this json file as an include, I use this one throughout my asp application without issues. https://www.gbca.org.au/global/json2.min.asp

Comment: I'm using myJson.Files.Url to get the url? This should return it yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted. I needed to specify the position in the array, which is strange cause I never needed to do this in other functions.

varFileUrl = myJson.Files.[0].Url

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `content-type:application/octet-stream` and you will get file stream instead of JSON, after that you can easily dump that stream into a file. The advantage of using steam response is:

- Response size will be smaller about 30% than JSON because JSON file
  data needs to be encoded in Base64,
- You can read data in chunks.

If you still prefer using JSON then remove StoreFile=true from your request and you will get a File Data instead of URl, decode it using base64 and write to file. You will save one request to the server.

Answer (score 0):

ConvertApi using json this is the easiest way covert PNG TO SVG:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "JSON",
    url: 'https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/png/to/svg?Secret=SECRET TOKEN HERE',
    type:"POST",
    data: {File:'IMAGE URL HERE',StoreFile:true},
    success: function(res){
      //console.log(res)
      console.log(res.Files[0].Url)
    }
  });
});
```